# can't get all image urls right in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

for a personal project, I am trying to scrape this webpage:

https://www.ebay.com/b/Jordan-11-Retro-Cool-Grey-2001/15709/bn_7117643306

trying to get all img URLs, using Selenium.

here is the code:

```
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Jordan-11-Retro-Cool-Grey-2001/15709/bn_7117643306'

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# open url
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/mreznik/V5/chromedriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
browser.get(url)

elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute('src'))
```

and it gets me a list of results:

```
...
https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/M-sAAOSwahdgrd0x/s-l300.webp
https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/bpUAAOSwoa9gtlWw/s-l300.webp
https://ir.ebaystatic.com/cr/v/c1/s_1x2.gif
...
```

as one can see by running this, these are listings on the page who's URL is not on the list - and stranger yet, images here that are not on the page!

how can I get this right?

Comment: What you wish to get? Only links inside products images?

Comment: yes, ty - only those

Answer (score 2):

You should get only the elements containing products images.
Please try this:

```
product_img_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"s-item")]//img'
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(product_img_xpath)
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute('src'))
```

Don't forget some delay / wait before getting the elements list, something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

product_img_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"s-item")]//img'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, product_img_xpath)))
time.sleep(1)

imgs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(product_img_xpath)
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute('src'))
```

**UPD**
In case you still not getting all the elements in the list please try scrolling to the element before accessing it properties.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

product_img_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"s-item")]//img'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, product_img_xpath)))
time.sleep(1)

imgs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(product_img_xpath)
for img in imgs:
    actions.move_to_element(img).perform()
    print(img.get_attribute('src'))
```

Comment: at least in my machine, this get around half of the listing's images - far from all, and not more than my own solution

Comment: Please try updated answer. this should work correct

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not - does it work on your machine?

Comment: I do not have Python at all on my computer, but I have some experience with Selenium... What exactly doesn't work now?  You are getting too short list of elements with `imgs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(product_img_xpath)` ? Did you try exactly what I wrote here? I have edited the answer 2-3 times.

Comment: In case it still doesn't get all the elements links please see the updated answer - scrolling to the elements before getting their `src` attribute.

Comment: it retrieves 9 listing URLs and the page has 11 - also, one of the urls is https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/bpUAAOSwoa9gtlWw/s-l300.webp which is not in the page at all

Comment: I see 17 results on the link you provided